# MVC post Array of values to Action using jquery AjaxForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've html elements which will are in a form of arrays and I would like to POST them and hope that MVC can bind the data correctly the specified model, no luck this far.

HTML 1 - with file upload, image position and description:

```
<p>
        <input id="Image-0 name="Images[0][Image]" type="file" placeholder="Images" accept="jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff" data-increment="1" />
        <em class="clear block" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></em>

        <input id="Position-0" name="Images[0][Position]" type="text" placeholder="Position e.g. 0-199" value="0" />
        <em class="clear block" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></em>

        <textarea id="Description-0" name="Images[0][Description]" placeholder="Description" style="height: 34px;"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="Image-1" name="Images[1][Image]" type="file" placeholder="Images" accept="jpg|jpeg|png|gif|tiff" data-increment="1" />
        <em class="clear block" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></em>

        <input id="Position-1" name="Images[1][Position]" type="text" placeholder="Position e.g. 0-199" value="0" />
        <em class="clear block" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></em>

        <textarea id="Description-1" name="Images[1][Description]" placeholder="Description" style="height: 34px;"></textarea>
    </p>
```

..and the Model part 1:

```
public IEnumerable<VehicleImageModel> Images { get; set; }
```

..Here's what VehicleImageModel consists of (basically the 3 html inputs above):

```
public class VehicleImageModel
{
    [Display( Name = "Position" )]
    public Int32 Position { get; set; }

    [Display( Name = "Description" )]
    public String Description { get; set; }

    [Display( Name = "Image" )]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
}
```

In my jquery I've added traditional=true as most people have suggested and that didn't work either, like below:

```
var options =
            {
                traditional: true,
                target: "#vehicle-list", // target element to be updated with server response 
                beforeSubmit: function ()
                {

                },  // pre-submit callback 
                success: function ()
                {

                }  // post-submit callback 
            };

            $("#vehicle-form").ajaxForm(options);
```

Is there something I'm missing maybe? Please help.

Comment: Try putting  .  between the name part of you inputs. e.g. name="Images[0].[Description]"

Comment: And I don't think you need the '[' ']' on the variable Name: name="Images[0].Description"

Comment: Hi @DawoodAwan, no luck with either of the 2 options, the Images on the model is NULL.

Comment: Could you post the code of you controller Method

Comment: @DawoodAwan, finally came right with this post http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/, I didn't clearly read your 2nd comment!

Comment: Use the strongly typed html helpers to avoid these sorts of issues (and give you other benefits such as client and server side validation) - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Images.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Images[i].Description) ..}` and then you can post back your model.